# Include_recursive does not accept the absolute path

Tags: icinga, icinga2, icingaweb2

Include_recursive in windows is not accepting absolute path when i use drive name in it. For example, include_recursive “C:/ProgramData/icinga2/opt/icinga2/config” is not working but include_recursive “/ProgramData/icinga2/opt/icinga2/config” is working. 
Did anyone encounter the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known bug, fixed in https://github.com/Icinga/icinga2/issues/5168 and soon released in v2.7.